# Dart BLE description for ease of coding?

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

An architecture question:
I have a BLE device with a number of variables... and the variables can be brought in from XML, eg

```
<!--Automation IO-->
  <service advertise="false" id="automation_io" name="Automation IO" requirement="mandatory" sourceId="BLE" type="primary" uuid="1815">
    <informativeText>Abstract:  The Automation IO service is used to expose the analog inputs/outputs and digital input/outputs of a generic IO module (IOM).  </informativeText>
    
    <!--Output-->
    <characteristic id="Output" name="Output" sourceId="xxx" uuid="1230">
      <informativeText>Summary:  The Digital characteristic is used to expose and change the state of an IO Module's digital signals.  </informativeText>
      <value length="1" type="user" variable_length="false">0</value>
      <properties indicate="false" indicate_requirement="optional" notify="true" notify_requirement="optional" read="true" read_requirement="optional"/>
    </characteristic>
        
    <!--ElectronicsTemp-->
    <characteristic id="ElectronicsTemp" name="ElectronicsTemp" sourceId="xxx" uuid="1235">
      <informativeText>Summary:  The Digital characteristic is used to expose and change the state of an IO Module's digital signals.  </informativeText>
      <value length="2" type="user" variable_length="false">23</value>
      <properties notify="true" notify_requirement="mandatory" read="true" read_requirement="mandatory"/>
    </characteristic>
    
    <!--MaxElectronicsTemp-->
    <characteristic id="MaxElectronicsTemp" name="MaxElectronicsTemp" sourceId="xxx" uuid="123E">
      <informativeText>Summary:  The Digital characteristic is used to expose and change the state of an IO Module's digital signals.  </informativeText>
      <value length="2" type="user" variable_length="false">23</value>
      <properties notify="true" notify_requirement="mandatory" read="true" read_requirement="mandatory"/>
    </characteristic>
    
    <!--SelfTest-->
    <characteristic id="SelfTest" name="SelfTest" sourceId="xxx" uuid="1236">
      <informativeText>Summary:  The Digital characteristic is used to expose and change the state of an IO Module's digital signals.  </informativeText>
      <value length="1" type="user" variable_length="false">00</value>
      <properties indicate="false" indicate_requirement="optional" notify="true" notify_requirement="optional" read="true" read_requirement="optional" write="true" write_no_response="true" write_no_response_requirement="optional" write_requirement="optional"/>
    </characteristic>
 ...
```

And the question is how to form it into something that's best-usable for FlutterBlue et all.

Right Now I have

```
class Intercom{
  static const PatchTo = "665c1cbc-2c88-4ae1-9ccf-9dbc8a9e5440";
  static const PhoneBook = "78805e56-f8b7-4f30-a056-2ece9f4f70a9";
  static const AllCall = "2ac8";
  static const StatusWord = "1239";
...
}

{
    BluetoothCharacteristic patchto =
        bleFindChar(services, Intercom.PatchTo)!;
    await patchto.write([0xFF, 0xFF]);
}
```

---

So the question:
Would it be best to keep in this vein -- that way I can add more and more to Class Intercom (like dataformat, tostring, etc)...

Or keep that separate?

Maybe Intercom should derive from FlutterBlue and suck in everything so that I would smiply say `Intercom.PatchTo(0xFFFF)` ?

Is there a way to load the put the XML file into a Flutter project and present itself as a data structure, or do I need to write a small Python script to take the XML and make a .dart file out of it?

Answer (score 0):

The [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package allows you to parse, traverse, query, transform and building XML documents in Dart (and Flutter). The tutorial in the package description explains how to load an XML file and extract data. Feel free to post more concrete questions on StackOverflow or GitHub.

Comment: Of course, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add the XML file to the Assets had be able to intellisense
Intercom.patchTo(0xFFFF);

So... can dart/flutter/VSCode do that or should I make Dart Generator python script that inputs the XML and outputs a .dart class file?

Comment: I am sorry, then I don't understand what you are asking? Of course you can use Dart to generate Dart code.